# How do you launch an instance with EIP straight away?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Having trouble with attaching eip to ec2 instance. I can only do it be assigning public ip then after instance is built then attaching eip. I want to add the EIP before the instance builds.

```
resource "aws_instance" "third-WG" {
    provider                    = aws.third
    ami                         = data.aws_ami.ubuntu3.id
    instance_type               = "t2.micro"
    key_name                    = aws_key_pair.third_WGkey.key_name
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    private_ip                  = "10.3.0.10"
    subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.third-WG-Subnet.id
    vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.third-SG.id]
    depends_on                  = [aws_instance.WG_DL_SRV]
}

   resource "aws_eip" "third_WG_EIP" {
   provider                  = aws.third
   vpc                       = true
   instance                  = aws_instance.third-WG.id
   depends_on                = [aws_internet_gateway.third-IGW]
   provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "echo ${aws_eip.third_WG_EIP.public_ip} > ~/Desktop/whole- 
       wash/var/3rd_PUB_IP.txt"
   }
     tags = {
        Name = "third_WG_EIP"
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of attaching the Elastic IP to the instance, which makes the instance a dependency of the Elastic IP forcing it to be built first, you can instead create a network interface, and attach the Elastic IP to that.  You then *also* make that interface used by the instance, and so everything is then brought up together.

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "nic" {
    private_ips          = ["10.3.0.10"]
    subnet_id            = aws_subnet.third-WG-Subnet.id
    #Todo: populate any other needed NIC parameters
} 

resource "aws_eip" "third_WG_EIP" {
   provider                  = aws.third
   vpc                       = true
   network_interface         = aws_network_interface.nic
   depends_on                = [aws_internet_gateway.third-IGW]
   provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "echo ${aws_eip.third_WG_EIP.public_ip} > ~/Desktop/whole- 
       wash/var/3rd_PUB_IP.txt"
   }
     tags = {
        Name = "third_WG_EIP"
    }
 }

resource "aws_instance" "third-WG" {
    provider                    = aws.third
    ami                         = data.aws_ami.ubuntu3.id
    instance_type               = "t2.micro"
    key_name                    = aws_key_pair.third_WGkey.key_name
    associate_public_ip_address = true

    vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.third-SG.id]
    depends_on                  = [aws_instance.WG_DL_SRV]

    network_interface {
        network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.nic.id
        device_index         = 0
    }

}
```

If you find it's still in slightly the wrong order, you can also then add the EIP to the `depends_on` parameter of the instance, since the EIP is no longer dependent on the instance itself.

Note that it's been a while since I've done precisely this, you may find you need to move a few of the other networky type parameters (security groups etc) out of the instance and into the network interface block.

Comment: Will this create the instance with EIP straight away? I just want to remove some bash, so i do not have cat a ip when the public address changes for wireguard config.